# Reduce colors from Millions to Thousands

Tags: macos, display, keynote, color

I was trying to run a Keynote presentation on a secondary display and Keynote told me that I didn't have enough video RAM and either needed to reduce the resolution or number of colors from Millions to Thousands.  I know how to change the resolution, but how do I change the number of colors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, the option to change color depth was removed in Snow Leopard. [SwitchResX](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html) can still do it I think, but that's shareware (10-day demo).

Comment: I have SwitchResX and didn't see that option.  Too bad they removed it.  Guess I am stuck.  I'll look at SwitchResX again though.  Thanks!

Comment: I just tried SwitchResX and I believe I found the option for "changing color depth."  If you open SwitchResX, you should see a little monitor icon in your menu bar.  Click this icon and a drop down menu will appear.  From the dropdown menu, select your display.  Another dropdown menu will appear and in this menu you should see the option for switching between "Millions of colors" and "Billions of colors."

Comment: What do you mean with little monitor incon in the menu bar? I see color lcd at the bottom and aboutswitchresx at the top. Can you help me out how to reduce the color depth?